# Using Makefile to add new source code files to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, gcc, makefile

I'm working on adding some functionality to the storage manager module in Postgresql.
I have added few source files already to the smgr folder, and I was able to have the Make system includes them by adding their names to the OBJS list in the Makefile inside the smgr folder. (i.e. When I add A.c, I would add A.o to the OBJS list).

That was working fine. Now I'm trying to add a new file hdfs_test.c to the project. The problem with this file is that it requires some extra directives in its compilation command (-I and -L directives).

The gcc command is:

```
gcc hdfs_test.c -I/HDFS_HOME/hdfs/src/c++/libhdfs -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -L/HDFS_HOME/hdfs/src/c++/libhdfs -L/HDFS_HOME/build/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib -L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/i386/server -ljvm -lhdfs -o hdfs_test
```

Therefore, simply adding hdfs_test.o to the OBJS list doesn't work.
I tried editing the Makefile to look like this:

```
OBJS = md.o smgr.o smgrtype.o A.o B.o hdfs_test.o

MyRule1 : hdfs_test.c
gcc tati.c -c -I/diskless/taljab1/Workspace/HDFS_Append/hdfs/src/c++/libhdfs -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -L/diskless/taljab1/Workspace/HDFS_Append/hdfs/src/c++/libhdfs -L/diskless/taljab1/Workspace/HDFS_Append/build/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib -L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/i386/server -ljvm -lhdfs
```

but it didn't work out, and I kept getting errors message of the Make trying to compile hdfs_test.c without including the directives.

How do I enforce the Make to include my compilation directives for hdfs_test.c ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pass `-l` and `-L` at compile time, only at link time. At compile time only `-I` (include path) directives are required to help the compiler find any extra headers.

You should compile your source file to a `.o` file, same as all the others. Then add the `-L` and `-l` directives to the link command line when the linker is invoked to create the `postgres` executable. That means all you need to edit in `src/backend/storage/smgr/Makefile` is the `OBJS` line to add your output object, as you've already done below. Remove your custom rule, it's unnecessary as well as incorrect.

Just add your extra libraries to the `$(LIBS)` make variable and add your `-L` paths to `$(LDFLAGS)` via `src/Makefile.global`. `src/Makefile.global` is generated by `configure` from `src/Makefile.global.in` so you actually need to modify `configure`'s behavior to add your includes, library paths and libraries. Don't edit `configure` directly either; edit `configure.in` and re-generate it with `autoconf`.

Yes, GNU Autotools is sometimes referred to as autohell for a reason. It's a bit ... interesting ... to work with sometimes, and there can be a lot of indirection involved in doing simple things.

Comment: Hi Craig.. Can you please specify some more details?
First, how do I add the extra include folders to $(LIBS)?
Can I do something like: LIBS=/IncludeFolder1:/IncludeFolder2 inside the inner makefile (the one in the folder smgr)?

I also checked the Makefile.global.in and didn't know exactly where to add my Linking folders to LDFLAGS.
For example, I found this:
ifdef PGXS
  LDFLAGS = -L$(libdir)
else
  LDFLAGS = -L$(top_builddir)/src/port
endif
LDFLAGS += @LDFLAGS
Can I add after this: LDFLAGS += /LinkFolder1  then LDFLAGS += /LinkFolder2 ?
And after that how do I use autoconf?
Thanks

Comment: Don't mess with the Makefiles directly except to add your file to OBJS. Modify $(LIBS) by getting `configure` to add them to the `Makefile` it produces. To learn more about autoconf, I suggest you look at one of the many tutorials and the documentation.

Basically, you need to learn how autoconf and make work; that's not something I can teach in a StackOverflow comment. See tutorials.

Comment: Also: You can't add to `LIBS` from the inner makefile, since recursive make doesn't propagate variable changes back up the call tree. You have to do it from the `Makefile` where the linker for `postgres` is called - or better, do it the *right* way by modifying configure to add to `$(LIBS)` in the `Makefile` generated from `Makefile.in`.

Comment: Checking in almost 9 years later to say thanks so much! This helped me a lot. Was stuck on this for a while